# Excel VBA: Generate N Number of Sheets Based on Cel Value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro that will generate N number of template sheets based on the value of a cel. For example, User inputs 4 into this particular cell and it subsequently generates 4 new sheets in the workbook of this template.

I've searched all through Stack overflow for a question that matches mine but none do. The closest I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363163/excel-vba-insert-n-number-of-sheets-based-on-cell-value) and although the inital headline question asks generally the same question, when going into detail the user who asked this changes their question to"insert number of cells based on a cell value". Still I used this as a starting point.

```
Sub CreateSheets()
  Dim facilitiesNum As Integer

   facilitiesNum = Range("B2").Value

  sheetsNeeded = facilitiesNum
  With ThisWorkbook.Sheets

  For i = sheetsNeeded To Master.Range("B2").Value2
  .Item("TemplateSheet").Copy After:=.Item(.Count)
  .Item(.Count).Name = sheetsNeeded
  Next
  End With
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA so I could be very off syntax-wise but in pseudocode my goal is

```
      numberOfTemplates = cell value
      numSheetsNeeded = numberOfTemplates

    For i = numSheetsNeeded To NumOfTemp:
    create sheets using numSheetsNeeded as reference for how many need to be 
    generated
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Well, what's the purpose of `sheetsNeeded = facilitiesNum` when `sheetsNeeded` isn't changed in code? Wouldn't it be simpler to use `facilitiesNum` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to add new sheets this should be enough

```
Sub CreateSheets()

   Dim facilitiesNum As Long

   facilitiesNum = Range("B2").Value

   With ThisWorkbook.Sheets
      For i = 1 To facilitiesNum
          .Item("TemplateSheet").Copy After:=.Item(.Count)
          .Item(.Count).Name = i
      Next i
   End With
end sub
```